# Issue in accessing the array values in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, pymongo

Here is a record from my mongoDB. I am trying to query it and using Pymongo.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5925665bcb98a11aa4ca23f8"),
        "EMAIL" : "jaffer@example.com",

        "LOGIN" : [
                "example"
        ],
        "NAME" : [
                "example name"
        ],
        "URL" : [
                "http://example.com"
        ]
}
```

I am trying to access the documents where the Key `NAME` is available.
I tried to query something like this:

```
db.ff.find({"NAME":[]})
db.ff.find({"NAME":[1]})
```

I do not get any output.
When I made the specific query the result appeared.

```
db.ff.find({"NAME":["example name"]})
```

But I do not know how many records has `NAME` as array key. Kindly, let me know how to find the record that have the Array Key as `NAME`.

Comment: @felix Thank you this help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use `$exists` and `$ne` to find the value

```
db.ff.find({ "NAME": { $exists: true, $ne: null } })
```